# LLBLGEN - Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, llblgenpro

How do I get LLBLGEN to output to POCOs instead of .hbm.xml files?

1) I have selected the Framework as NHibernate but there does not seem to be any settings in the project properties to change the output type.

2) I thought maybe I needed to download FluentNHibernate separately and just drop it into the Frameworks directory of LLBLGEN but there seems to be .framework and .frameworksettings files required also which are not part of the FluentNHibernate download.

Any ideas?

Comment: IN NHibernate you have your POCOs and corresponding mappings (.hbm.xml) therefor LLBLGEN should create both

Answer (score 0):

LLBLGen Pro generates poco classes with the hbm.xml files, as stated in the docs. Did you select the preset which only generates the mapping files? Select the preset which generates poco's + hbm.xml files.